# e(fx)clipse - Tutorial2 - step 18 - can't generate update site

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, javafx-2, p2, efxclipse

Tutorial2 – e(fx)clipse - step 18 - Problem occurred

I am following
http://www.efxclipse.org/trac/wiki/Tutorial2

At step 18: generate update site with button )Build All(

> 18 : The result of the operation should look similar to the screenshot
>   below

. ...

But I actually got "Problem occurred"

[image]

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

Error
Thu Apr 04 21:51:03 CST 2013
An internal error occurred during: "Build Site".

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at/bestsolution/efxclipse/tooling/pde/adaptor/IClasspathContributor
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.BuildUtilities.getBootClasspath(BuildUtilities.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.createAntBuildProperties(FeatureExportOperation.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureBasedExportOperation.run(FeatureBasedExportOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.SiteBuildOperation.run(SiteBuildOperation.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered your question already yesterday on the [e(fx)clipse forum](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/efxclipse). This is a bug caused by the fact that we have to fix the PDE-Classpath-Container in a very nasty way.

Comment: It is torture to use e(fx)clipse forum https://groups.google.com/d/forum/efxclipse and Google services in general in China now.